# how to give access to phpmyadmin to the resource on kali linux?

Tags: phpmyadmin

how to fix this problem of phpmyadmin

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

on kali linux Debian 11?

phpmyadmin.conf

```
Alias /pma /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
  Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  # Autoriser accès depuis certaines adresses IP / sous-réseau
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 192.168.1.0/24

  <IfModule mod_php.c>
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
      AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    </IfModule>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

    php_value include_path .
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
    
    php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/
    
    php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload 0
  </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Désactiver accès web sur certains dossiers
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates>
  Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
  Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
  Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Comment: Does your webserver error log contain any hints?

Comment: What is the IP address of the web server running phpMyAdmin and what is the IP address of your client machine? Do either of the servers have more than one network card (NIC)?